# Why does New Relic list "/System.ServiceModel.Activation.AspNetRouteServiceHttpHandler" under slow web transactions?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, newrelic

I am using New Relic to gather performance metrics on a .NET 3.5 web service. New Relic tells me that the most time consuming web transaction in this application is "/System.ServiceModel.Activation.AspNetRouteServiceHttpHandler". I have done some research and understand that this is related to handling HTTP requests to a WCF application, but I do not understand why it appears as it's own web transaction in New Relic. Does anybody have any suggestions on why this might be happening?

Comment: Without looking deployment in your IIS and analize your app it is hard to tell. But be shure that there is somthing which is calling some route under which this activation handler is responding.

Answer (score -1):

New Relic's .NET agent names transactions using the tracer in the transaction with the highest naming priority. Web transactions may be named using the http handler, asp name, MVC controller name, or web service name depending on the tracers invoked in the transaction's execution. Background transactions with no tracer which explicitly name the transaction are rolled up into a single transaction name.

You can set up custom instrumentation with customized naming for greater visibility into your code, the process is documented here: https://newrelic.com/docs/dotnet/CustomInstrumentation#metrics

If you need more help with this, I'd recommend opening a ticket with us at https://support.newrelic.com/